# VBA - Loop, Catch error, assign variable and continue looping?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this email automation program. I essentially want to create a error catch for `RecpName`. When `RecpName` is passed into Lotus Notes and returns an error (due to spelling errors), I want to capture that into a error catch.

I still want the loop to keep going and continue down the list, but tell the user which names it couldn't send emails to.

Here's my code:

```
Sub Send_HTML_Email()

    Const ENC_IDENTITY_8BIT = 1729

    'Send Lotus Notes email containing links to files on local computer

    Dim NSession As Object      'NotesSession
    Dim NDatabase As Object     'NotesDatabase
    Dim NStream As Object       'NotesStream
    Dim NDoc As Object          'NotesDocument
    Dim NMIMEBody As Object     'NotesMIMEEntity
    Dim SendTo As String
    Dim subject As String
    Dim HTML As String, HTMLbody As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lstrow As Long, j As Long
    Dim RecpName As String, candiName As String
    Dim a As Hyperlink

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Detail")

    ' Instantiate the Lotus Notes COM's Objects.

    lstrow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set NSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")       'using Lotus Notes Automation Classes (OLE)
    Set NDatabase = NSession.GetDatabase("", "")

    If Not NDatabase.IsOpen Then NDatabase.OPENMAIL

    For j = 3 To lstrow
        RecpName = ws.Cells(j, 2).Text
        candiName = ws.Cells(j, 1).Text

        SendTo = RecpName
        subject = wb.Worksheets("Email Settings").Range("B1").Text
        Debug.Print subject

        Set NStream = NSession.CreateStream

        HTMLbody = "<p>" & "Hi " & ws.Cells(j, 2).Text & "," & "</p>" & _
        vbCrLf & _
        "<p>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(2, 2).Text & vbCrLf & _
        Sheets("Detail").Cells(j, 1).Text & "</p>" & vbCrLf & _
        "<p>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(3, 2).Text & _
        "<br>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(4, 2).Text & _
        "<br>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(5, 2).Text & _
        "<br>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(6, 2).Text & "</p>" & _
        "<p>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(9, 2).Text & _
        "<br>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(10, 2).Text & _
        "<br>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(11, 2).Text & _
        "<br>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(12, 2).Text & _
        "<br>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(13, 2).Text & _
        "<br>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(14, 2).Text & _
        "<br>" & Sheets("Email Settings").Cells(15, 2).Text & "</p>"

        HTML = "<html>" & vbLf & _
               "<head>" & vbLf & _
               "<meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=UTF-8""/>" & vbLf & _
               "</head>" & vbLf & _
               "<body>" & vbLf & _
               HTMLbody & _
               "</body>" & vbLf & _
               "</html>"

        NSession.ConvertMime = False     'Don't convert MIME to rich text

        Set NDoc = NDatabase.CreateDocument()

        With NDoc
            .Form = "Memo"
            .subject = subject
            .SendTo = Split(SendTo, ",")

            Set NMIMEBody = .CreateMIMEEntity
            NStream.WriteText HTML
            NMIMEBody.SetContentFromText NStream, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", ENC_IDENTITY_8BIT

            .Send False
            .Save True, False, False
        End With

        NSession.ConvertMime = True      'Restore conversion

    Next j
    Set NDoc = Nothing
    Set NSession = Nothing
    MsgBox "The e-mail has successfully been created and distributed", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this code can help you:

```
Sub Send_HTML_Email()

    Dim cnt_err As Integer: cnt_err = 1
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Const ENC_IDENTITY_8BIT = 1729

    ' Insert the rest of the code here

    MsgBox "The e-mail has successfully been created and distributed", vbInformation

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    ' Insert code to handle the error, e.g.
    wb.Worksheets("SheetToSaveMailsNotSent").Range("A" & cnt) = RecpName
    cnt = cnt + 1        
    ' The next instruction will continue the subroutine execution
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

For more help you can go to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hsw66as.aspx).

HTH ;)

Comment: This is exactly how I started to write the Error Handler,  I do appreciate this! Essentially inside the errorhandler, I could paste RecpName to a Sheet, and just use Resume Next?

Comment: I edited my answer @Jaz . See if it is what you need ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance! I figured this was the logic to go thorough, this helps me greatly :)

Comment: If you do not need any more help with this question and you feel that this is a valid answer do not forget to accept it :-)